# How to reduce contrast of a NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, data-augmentation, contrast

I want to reduce the contrast of my whole dataset as an experiment. The dataset is in a NumPy array of `np.array(X).reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)` I tried to use the library Albumentations, which works really well for motion blur and Gaussian noise, but I didn't find a way to reduce the contrast with that library. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to rescale the difference to the mean value, here is an example, using [this image](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Qurban-Memon/publication/316186591/figure/fig3/AS:484349654114306@1492489364797/a-600-600-image-of-a-building.png) as source. Extra code using PIL and `imshow` for visuals:

```
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = PIL.Image.open('a-600-600-image-of-a-building.jpg')
np_im = np.array(im)
np_mean = np.mean(np.array(im))

for factor in [1.0, 0.9, 0.5, 0.1]:
    plt.figure()
    plt.title("{}".format(factor))
    reduced_contrast=(np_im-np_mean)*factor + np_mean
    new_im = PIL.Image.fromarray(reduced_contrast)
    plt.imshow(np.array(list(new_im.convert('RGBA').getdata())).reshape(new_im.height, new_im.width, 4))
    plt.savefig("{}.png".format(factor))
```

Output:

[image: 1.0]
[image: 0.9]
[image: 0.5]
[image: 0.1]

The relevant line is `reduced_contrast=(np_im-np_mean)*factor + np_mean`

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation!

Comment: I tried this method in my code, but for some reason, it didn't change anything about the picture. I feel like there is a problem with the np.mean as I am trying to make all the dataset have a reduce contrast

Comment: The problem is not np.mean itself but the problem is that I am not converting my image from an array put I am printing the array itself. How could I do this without me converting it into a PIL.Image?

Comment: Include a MWE in your original question of your code, it's difficult to debug from descriptions